# Scala - how to refactor a method to use reduceLeft instead of iterating?

Tags: java, scala, collections

I have a Java background and have recently started learning Scala. I've implemented a method that still looks to me more like a Java style. How can it be improved using various Scala features to be more Scala-like method?

I have an idea to use `reduceLeft` like

`val sales: List[Sale] = salesList.sortBy(_.timestamp)`

```
sales.reduceLeft(someFunction)
```

And the function could have a signature similar to

```
  def reduceSalesFunction: (Sale, Sale) => Sale= {
     ???
  }
```

Here is how I implemented the method. Is there a space for improvements?

```
def processSales(sales: List[Sale]): Sale = {
    // if just a single sale, get it
    if (sales.size == 1) sales.iterator.next 

    else {
      // get the oldest sale
      val sortedSales = sales.sortWith(_.timestamp < _.timestamp)
      val oldestSale: Sale = sortedSales.min
      val salesMetrics: Metrics = oldestSale.metrics

      // update the oldest sale's metrics
      for (sale <- sortedSales) {
        val metrics: Metrics = sale.metrics
        if (metrics.isMetric_1) salesMetrics.setIsMetric_1(metrics.isMetric_1)
        if (metrics.isMetric_2) salesMetrics.setIsMetric_2(metrics.isMetric_2)
        if (metrics.isMetric_3) salesMetrics.setIsMetric_3(metrics.isMetric_3)
      }

      // if there are metrics with `false` values set the oldest sale's metrics to `false` as well (Metrics is an Enum)
      for (metric <- Metrics.values(); if !salesMetrics.isSet(metric)) {
        salesMetrics.setMetricValue(metric, false)
      }
      oldestSale
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add some example inputs and their expected results?

Comment: i can't flag it, but shouldn't this be on codereview.stackexchange?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley I think you are right. Should I delete it from here then?

Comment: I don't know if you can migrate it, but sth like that, yeah

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question belongs to another site codereview.stackexchange.com. codereview.stackexchange.com is not displayed in the list of another site option.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 1):

I have some style suggestions for you:

- Do not call a method `getSomthting` it is not a getter, I think is
  valid for Java too.
- You may replace `if else` with the pattern matching.

Example:

```
sales match {
  // if just a single sale, get it
  case x :: Nil => x
  // get the oldest sale
  case other    => //your logic
}
```

- Looking to use the same pattern for the type inference.

Choose one of:

```
  val sortedSales: List[Sale] = sales.sortWith(_.timestamp < _.timestamp)
  val oldestSale: Sale = sortedSales.min
  val salesMetrics: Metrics = oldestSale.metrics
```

Or

```
  val sortedSales = sales.sortWith(_.timestamp < _.timestamp)
  val oldestSale = sortedSales.min
  val salesMetrics = oldestSale.metrics
```

- Avoid using "_" for your methods/fields naming when is possible(`isMetric_1`).
- Do not use ";". Line separated blocks are more readable.

Example:

```
for { 
  metric <- Metrics.values()
  if !salesMetrics.isSet(metric)
} salesMetrics.setMetricValue(metric, false)
```

- Another good practice is the use of immutable structure.

**P.S.:**

It is just my opinion. It's up to your team!

I strongly recommend taking a look at https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/.

And enjoy Scala! :)

Comment: I wonder if it can be simplified with `reduceLeft` like `val sales: List[Sale] = salesList.sortBy(_.timestamp)` `sales.reduceLeft(someFunction)` ?

Comment: I think in your case it could be something similar at: `sortedSales.reduce { case (acc, sales) =>
  if (sales.metrics.isMetric_1) acc.metrics.setIsMetric_1(metrics.isMetric_1)
  if (sales.metrics.isMetric_2) acc.metrics.setIsMetric_2(metrics.isMetric_2)
  if (sales.metrics.isMetric_3) acc.metrics.setIsMetric_3(metrics.isMetric_3)
  acc
}`